Python importing CSV, adding square brackets
I have the following code:
# Read serial numbers from CSV
with open('serials.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    serials = [row for row in reader]

# Query warranty date for each serial number and update CSV
for row in serials:
    
    data = {"sn": row}
    response = requests.post(url, json=data)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        warranty_info = response.json()
        warranty_expire_date = warranty_info.get('warrantyInfo', {}).get('warrantyExpireDate')
        row.append(warranty_expire_date)
    else:
        row.append("Failed to retrieve")

This opens a CSV file and reads each serial number of each line, they are stored as simply as:
serial1
serial2
serial3

The idea is then I submit JSON in the format of:
{'sn': "serial1"}

The issue I have is that it it trying to submit it in the format of:
{'sn': "['serial1']"}

I presume [] means it's a list, but I can't understand why it thinks it's a list.

Because each row is a list in a CSV. If it's just one value per line, you don't even need a CSV reader, just read the file line by line.

Why are you treating that as CSV? Each line is a list of one item because there are no commas. Also you're not actually serialising the data as JSON. Please do basic debugging it see what you're working with.

@jon json=data does the JSON serialisation for you…

@deceze yes, and it does it correctly - if they did have requests.post(url, json={"sn": ["serial1"]}), that would not get sent as they claim.

@jon That is true. I expect they're debugging it on the other side, and the receiving server is treating it as a string or such…

@deceze the single quotes make that relatively unlikely, unless they're sending and receiving correct JSON then using Python (or something else that defaults to single quotes) to turn it back into a string and then concluding they actually got the wrong thing. It's certainly not a [mre], this doesn't add up.

Each row is a list with one element for each column in the csv.
So you have to use the first element (if the data you are interested in is in the first column):
for row in serials:
    data = {"sn": row[0]}


Given that your CSV only contains a serial per line, I wouldn't even use a CSV reader for this, just to keep things simpler. This way of reading the CSV file should be good enough:
# Read serial numbers from CSV
with open('serials.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    serials = [serial.strip() for serial in infile.readlines()]

However, if you need to use a CSV reader, you can simply modify this line:
serials = [row for row in reader]

to be:
serials = [row[0] for row in reader]

The reason is that every row in a CSV can contain multiple values/columns, so the CSV reader wraps every row's values in a list. In this case, as you only have one column, you can safely access row[0] to get the serial for every row.

Your row only has one column, but it's still a row of data and is therefore a list.  You can either access the member of the list like row[0] or iterate over it.

You can try this like that :
# Read serial numbers from CSV
with open('serials.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    serials = [row for row in reader]

# Query warranty date for each serial number and update CSV
for row in serials:
    # Access the first element of the row list to get the serial number
    serial_number = row[0] if row else ""
    data = {"sn": serial_number}
    
    response = requests.post(url, json=data)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        warranty_info = response.json()
        warranty_expire_date = warranty_info.get('warrantyInfo', {}).get('warrantyExpireDate')
        row.append(warranty_expire_date)
    else:
        row.append("Failed to retrieve")

